# How do I Debug Print keys and values in dictionary using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using vba and have written certain values into the dictionary. However, I would like to see if information has been passed into the dictionary correctly. Hence, is it possible to debug.print keys and values in a dictionary to the immediate window?

I was thinking of this:

```
debug.print DicTemp.Items
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "first", 30
    dict.Add "second", 40
    dict.Add "third", 100

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key, dict(key)
    Next key

End Sub
```

It prints:

```
first          30 
second         40 
third          100
```

Comment: Worth noting that to use that Sub, the syntax is: Testme myDictionary  - not Testme(myDictionay)  - I have been banging my head for the past hour!

Comment: @lokxs - Just `TesteMe` should be enough, the dictionary is not an argument.

Comment: How do I pass a dictionary as an argument then in such a sub if the dictionary is not created within the sub like above? It worked in my case the way I did it, i.e.  
`Sub PrintDict(dict As Object)  
  
        Dim key As Variant  
        For Each key In dict.Keys  
            Debug.Print key, dict(key)  
        Next key  
  
    End Sub`
  
and in the main Sub:  
  
`PrintDict companyDict`     ' not `PrintDict(companyDict )`

Comment: @lokxs - if you edit the code of the `PrintDict()`, then yes.

Answer (score 5):

Loop through each dictionary key, and debug print:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print key, dict(key)
Next key
```