# Unable to Loop Through Dictionary Keys

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

For work, I'm creating a dictionary that takes information from an excel sheet that contains multiple product codes, as well as production dates and their corresponding quantities. The goal of the dictionary is to compile all the same codes into 1 row and add up the quantities into one row. For example, this is what my data currently looks like

```
               MON    TUES    WED    THURS    FRI
```

```
product 1              3       1               5
product 2       5              4       2
product 2       4              4       1
product 3              8                   
...
product n
```

And this is how I want the code to format it,

```
               MON    TUES    WED    THURS    FRI
```

```
product 1       2      3       4              5  
product 2       9              8       3
product 3              8                   
...
product n
```

In order to accomplish this, I stored multiple values in one key. The key is the product code and the production dates are the items. In order to store multiple values in the key, I used a class (using [this site](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Example_2_8211_Dealing_with_Multiple_Values) as guidance). I heavily used this site, and it's examples, as guidance I have not done this previously.

The issue I'm having is that every time I try to print the dictionary, whether to Debug.Print or a worksheet, I get a "424 object required" error. I'm not sure why I'm having this error, as I'm unable to even check if the dictionary is working correctly.

I have looked at multiple posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358530/how-do-i-debug-print-keys-and-values-in-dictionary-using-vba),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358530/how-do-i-debug-print-keys-and-values-in-dictionary-using-vba)), and sites, to try different methods of looping through the keys to see if they would yield a different result (they didn't).

Here's some of my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub concatenateData()

    Dim dictPC As Object
    Dim productCodes As clsProductCodes
    Dim wsCryovac As Worksheet
    Dim PLU As Integer
    Dim Friday As Integer
    Dim Saturday As Integer
    Dim Monday As Integer
    Dim Tuesday As Integer
    Dim Wednesday As Integer
    Dim Thursday As Integer
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set dictPC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wsCryovac = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cryovac")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lrow = wsCryovac.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For row = 4 To lrow

        PLU = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 1).Value2
        Friday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 2).Value2
        Saturday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 3).Value2
        Monday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 4).Value2
        Tuesday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 5).Value2
        Wednesday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 6).Value2
        Thursday = wsCryovac.Cells(row, 7).Value2

        If dictPC.Exists(PLU) = True Then
            Set productCodes = dictPC(PLU)
        Else
            Set productCodes = New clsProductCodes
            dictPC.Add PLU, productCodes
        End If

        dictPC(productCodes.PLU) = PLU
        dictPC(productCodes.Friday) = dictPC(productCodes.Friday) + Friday
        dictPC(productCodes.Saturday) = dictPC(productCodes.Saturday) + Saturday
        dictPC(productCodes.Monday) = dictPC(productCodes.Monday) + Monday
        dictPC(productCodes.Tuesday) = dictPC(productCodes.Tuesday) + Tuesday
        dictPC(productCodes.Wednesday) = dictPC(productCodes.Wednesday) + Wednesday
        dictPC(productCodes.Thursday) = dictPC(productCodes.Thursday) + Thursday

    Next row

    WriteToImmediate dictPC

End Sub
```

```
'This is where I attempt to check the dictionary information with code I used from: 
'https://excelmacromastery.com/vbadictionary/#Example_2_8211_Dealing_with_Multiple_Values
Private Sub WriteToImmediate(dictPC As Dictionary)

    Dim key As Variant, productCodes As clsProductCodes

    ' Read through the dictionary
    For Each key In dictPC.Keys
        Set productCodes = dictPC(key) 'I get the 424 error on this line
        With productCodes
            ' Write to the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)
            Debug.Print .PLU, .Friday, .Saturday, .Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday
        End With
    Next key

End Sub
```

To reiterate, the problem I'm having is that I get "424 object error" which I'm not sure how to fix, partly due to my inexperience using a dictionary.

Comment: `For Each key in dictPC.Keys`

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` would help with these kind of issues

Comment: @MarcoGetrost that was a typo! I have corrected in my question. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Zac I have 'Option Explicit' included in my code... just not here. I will add it in order to be clearer. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MarcoGetrost when I try that I get a 91 runtime error (object not set) at that line...

Comment: you need to show the line where you create the dict e.g. Set dictPC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Comment: @QHarr will do!

Comment: Please update your code to be a verifiable sample. You have `Option Explicit` but no `Sub` or `Function` definition, but there is an `End Sub`. It's not clear where your dictionary is defined. It's very hard to debug bits and pieces.

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't contain instances of clsProductCodes, only numbers(?)

Comment: @JNevill sorry, I will add the remainder of my code in order to be clearer.

Comment: @Tim Williams, sorry I'm not sure what you mean... from my understanding (given the site I was using) I thought I was saving the numbers to the dictionary

Comment: I'm presuming that both these sub's sit in the same module?

Comment: @Zac yep, they're both in the same module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mis-spoke above - you do have instances of `clsProductCodes` in your dictionary:

```
Set productCodes = New clsProductCodes
dictPC.Add PLU, productCodes
```

but then you do this:

```
    dictPC(productCodes.PLU) = PLU
    dictPC(productCodes.Friday) = dictPC(productCodes.Friday) + Friday
    dictPC(productCodes.Saturday) = dictPC(productCodes.Saturday) + Saturday
```

here you're not updating the object stored in the dictionary - you're adding new keys and values

I *think* you meant to do something more like this:

```
    dictPC(PLU).PLU = PLU
    dictPC(PLU).Friday = dictPC(PLU).Friday + Friday
    dictPC(PLU).Saturday = dictPC(PLU).Saturday + Saturday
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! That worked wonderfully! Thank you for the explanation - I really appreciate it!