# How to print classes from a dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary

I was working on implementing a dictionary that holds multiple values per key, so I adapted the code found in this tutorial/example: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Example_2_8211_Dealing_with_Multiple_Values

I created a class called `clsAI_App` with the following code:

```
Public ApplicationID As String
Public AIName As String
Public DoseApplied As Double
```

And in my module used the following bit:

```
For k = LBound(contents, 2) To UBound(contents, 2)
        Set oApplication = New clsAI_App
        oApplication.ApplicationID = Row & "-" & k
        oApplication.AIName = contents(1, k)
        oApplication.DoseApplied = contents(2, k) * wks_In.Cells(Row, 5)
        dict.Add oApplication.ApplicationID, oApplication
next k
```

Where `Row` and `k` are integer values and `contents()` is a matrix of (1,3)(1,5)

Now if I use the method for printing a dictionary as given as answers to [How do I Debug Print keys and values in dictionary using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358530/how-do-i-debug-print-keys-and-values-in-dictionary-using-vba) which is:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print key, dict(key) 
Next key
```

I end up with error 438:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Which has an overly broad description. So I am at a loss what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see the link you posted, but since you loaded an object (`oApplication`) and `Debug.Print` returns strings, you must adapt the code to return one string class property. I would try:

```
Debug.Print key, dict(key).DoseApplied...
```

If the class in discussion would have many such properties, you can extract all of them.

Dictionary is a powerful tool, being able to keep all sorts of variables, objects, even functions...